# Are public speeches in The Crown accurate?

Tags: realism, the-crown

The Crown tries to present a dramatisation of Queen Elizabeth's rise into power (or rather, the early years, at least in the first two seasons, I am aware that it will jump into a later period in later seasons).

Many scenes include speeches which would be very public, e.g. Churchill's eulogy or the Christmas speeches, or things which makes one move uncomfortably in their seat like the speeches in Kenya and the Bahamas, etc.

While I am certain that the sentiments are true to form, are they really taken from history, or are they part of the dramatisation?

In other words, I am sure that the private conversations between different characters are made up, perhaps with some basis in reality, or at least some extrapolation. But what about the public addresses? Are those taken verbatim, or dramatised, or completely rewritten for the story?

Comment: IMHO this is waaaay too broad: you expect someone to watch all episodes of The Crown, note down all public speeches that are referenced, transcribe all those speeches as featured in the show and then compare them to the one that were actually spoken. This is an absurd amount of work, work that you should do yourself if you're that interested in this subject.

Comment: Verbatim - I’m sure

Comment: @BCdotWEB - not necessarily - it's possible someone has knowledge of those speeches and can give a good account of how accurate they are - or they have insider knowledge or information about quotes from script-writers or something which give the answer (as often is the case on this site) - there are a few ways this could be answered without having to compare every single speech word-for-word...

Comment: @cmp Do you have a source?

Comment: One that's easy to compare - [Edward's abdication speech](https://www.historyplace.com/speeches/edward.htm). Somewhat ironically, I was the stand-in for Alex Jennings on set that day, so I had an hour or so to sit & read it at the desk in Hatfield House. I never thought to photograph it & compare it to the original ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I have just rewatched the abdication speech in The Crown (start of S01E03), and every word spoken is in the text you linked to - although it was not a full reading;  many sentences (and parts of sentences) of the actual speech were left out.  Given the obvious attention to detail of the series, I imagine the same would be true for all the public speeches shown - what's there would be accurate, but it is a TV drama that would be killed by full verbatim readings.

Comment: I still can’t believe this is getting so much attention. They have enough to deal with already with the show being dramatised too much. The famous ‘Balmoral test’ which doesn’t actually exist. I think they would have to be very foolish to mess around with speeches that the whole wide world heard.